Confidence interval for binomial distribution
I'm developing a simple application for memorization, for personal use. The user gives responses corresponding to prompts, and each prompt belongs to some category. At the end, we have for each category $c$, the user has given $s_c$ out of $n_c$ correct responses.
In general, $n_c$ can be very small (0 or 1).
I'd like to get a lower bound on the true accuracy of the user per category, using the responses as a sample. I think I should use a binomial confidence interval for this. I've looked through the Wikipedia article on the subject, but it's hard to get through the jargon. The article says:

Of the approximations listed above, Wilson score interval methods (with or without continuity correction) have been shown to be the most accurate and the most robust, though some prefer Agresti & Coulls' approach for larger sample sizes.

Since Wilson's is the most accurate, and my sample sizes are small, I am inclined to use the Wilson method. But there are other methods in the article not featured in the comparison (Jeffreys, Clopper-Pearson, Arcsine transformation, $t_a$ transform). How do I know which of these is right for me?

FAQ: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=exact+binomial+confidence+interval+is%3Aquestion.
